# Handling Kafka timeout exception Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka in my app and I want to handle timeout exceptions during kafka send message. I tried to do next: on callback throw Runtime exception and catch it in the method call.

This is kafka call:

```
public final class ManualKafkaBetsProducer implements IKafkaBetsProducer
{
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<ReportsBetKey, IReportsBet> template;

    public void send(IReportsBet bet)
    {
        template.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(bet).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, kafkaBetsTopicName)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, new ReportsBetKey(bet)).build())
                .addCallback(res -> logger.debug("Message {} send OK"), ex -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                });
    }
}
```

And this is method call:

```
try
{
    manualKafkaBetsProducer.send(bet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     return TransactionResultType.GENERAL_ERROR.name();
}
```

The problem is: when timeout expeption occurs, it doesn't go to the catch block. When some other error happens, it works ok.
Any ideas how to handle this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `send` method returns a `ListenableFuture<SendResult>`.

If you want to get an exception on the sending thread if the send failed, you could wait for this future to complete  (by calling `get()` on it) and check the result.

The `callback` is useful if you *don't* want the sending thread to wait. It gives you chance to have another thread pick up the results later.

Comment: If you don't block, the code moves on and you won't get an exception. You don't have to block immediately, you can inspect the Future later, but as soon as you need to know if there was an exception or not, you have to wait for the result.

Comment: You could also configure how long that Kafka producer will block at most (`max.block.ms`). Then you don't have to wait too long (but this may also interfere with how well the producer works -- sometimes there are network hiccups that you want to be covered).